# Count space required for RLE-compressed string

Tags: c++, string

I'm working on an interview workbook and am doing this problem: *Implement a function to compress a string using the counts of repeated characters (aabcccccaaa would become a2blc5a3). Return the original string if the "compressed" is not smaller than the original.*

A solution I found counts the size of the compressed string before anything else. I've tried tracing through this helper function don't understand the logic of this line. *Any help deciphering would be great!*:

**size = size + 1 + std::to_string(count).length();**

count is an int that is the number of repeated characters
In C++11, to_string lets you append append ints to strings. So, A+1 would be A1.

**Better solution:**

```
int countCompression(const string& str)
{
    if (str.length() == 0)
        return 0;

    char prev = str[0];
    int size = 0;
    int count = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        // Repeated char
        if (str[i] == prev)
            count++;
        // Unique char
        else
        {
            prev = str[i];
            size = size + 1 + std::to_string(count).length();
            count = 1;
        }
        //cout << "The size in iteration " << i << " is now " << size << endl;
    }
    size = size + 1 + std::to_string(count).length();
    //cout << "The final size is: " << size << endl;
    return size;
}
```

**BTW, I wrote this solution, but it checks the size afterwards. This wastes space I think:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string compress(const std::string &str)
{
    std::string comp;
    char prev = str[0];
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        if (prev == str[i])
            count++;
        else
        {
            comp += prev;
            comp += std::to_string(count);
            prev = str[i];
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    comp += prev;
    comp += std::to_string(count);
    if (comp.size() > str.size())
        return comp;
    else
        return str;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> size = size + 1 + std::to_string(count).length();

This line is incrementing `size` by 1 for the repeated character itself (`a`, `b`, `c`, etc) plus the `length()` of the string representation of the numeric `count` that specifies how many times the character is repeated.

Thus:

for `aa`, 2 is added to `size`:

```
size = size + 1 + to_string(2).length()
```

for `b`, 2 is added to `size`:

```
size = size + 1 + to_string(1).length()
```

for `ccccc`, 2 is added to size:

```
size = size + 1 + to_string(5).length()
```

for `aaa`, 2 is added to `size`:

```
size = size + 1 + to_string(3).length()
```

So the final compressed `size` is 8.

With that said, try this implementation:

```
std::string compress(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string::size_type len = str.length();
    if (len > 1) // compressed size is 2 chars minimum
    {
        std::ostringstring compressed;

        char ch, prev = str[i];
        int count = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i)
        {
            ch = str[i];
            if (ch == prev) {
                // Repeated char
                ++count;
            }
            else {
                // Unique char
                compressed << prev << count;
                prev = ch;
                count = 1;
            }
        }

        // output the final pending char count
        compressed << prev << count;

        std::string result = compressed.str();
        if (result.length() < len)
            return result;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Alernatively:

```
std::string::size_type compressSize(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string::size_type len = str.length();
    if (len > 1) // compressed size is 2 chars minimum
    {
        std::string::size_type size = 0;

        char ch, prev = str[i];
        int count = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i)
        {
            ch = str[i];
            if (ch == prev) {
                // Repeated char
                ++count;
            }
            else {
                // Unique char
                size += (1 + std::to_string(count).length());
                prev = ch;
                count = 1;
            }
        }

        // output the final pending char count
        size += (1 + std::to_string(count).length());

        if (size < len)
            return size;
    }

    return len;
}

std::string compress(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string::size_type len = str.length();

    if (compressSize(str) >= len)
        return str;

    std::ostringstring compressed;
    char ch, prev = str[i];
    int count = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i)
    {
        ch = str[i];
        if (ch == prev) {
            // Repeated char
            ++count;
        }
        else {
            // Unique char
            compressed << prev << count;
            prev = ch;
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    // output the final pending char count
    compressed << prev << count;

    return compressed.str();
}
```

Alternatively:

```
bool canCompress(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string::size_type len = str.length();
    if (len <= 1) // compressed size is 2 chars minimum
        return false;

    std::string::size_type size = 0;

    char ch, prev = str[i];
    int count = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i)
    {
        ch = str[i];
        if (ch == prev) {
            // Repeated char
            ++count;
        }
        else {
            // Unique char
            size += (1 + std::to_string(count).length());
            if (size >= len) {
                return false;
            }
            prev = ch;
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    // output the final pending char count
    size += (1 + std::to_string(count).length());

    return (size < len);
}

std::string compress(const std::string& str)
{
    if (!canCompress(str))
        return str;

    std::ostringstring compressed;

    char ch, prev = str[i];
    int count = 1;

    std::string::size_type len = str.length();
    for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i)
    {
        ch = str[i];
        if (ch == prev) {
            // Repeated char
            ++count;
        }
        else {
            // Unique char
            compressed << prev << count;
            prev = ch;
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    // output the final pending char count
    compressed << prev << count;

    return compressed.str();
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. Much clearer now thans. Can't I just say size = size + 2? I don't see why I need to convert the length() of the string representation of the numeric count then add it since it will always be +2 right?

Comment: In the example given, `size` will always be incremented by 2. But think of what happens if a character is repeated more than 9 times. The length of `count` by be more than 1 - add 1+1 for counts `1-9`, add 1+2 for counts 10-99, add 1+3 for counts 100-999, and so on. See the problem? That is why `count` is converted to a `string` and then its `length()` is added to `size`.

Answer (score 2):

It means *assign to* `size` *the result of adding together the following*:

- size
- 1
- the length of the string representation of *count*

That is, the length of the old compressed representation (`size`) plus what you need to represent the current run (1 for the character, plus the representation of the count).

Answer (score 2):

```
size = size + 1 + std::to_string(count).length();
```

For each tuple like `aaaa => a4`, at this code line, you have 4 in `count`.
In your target string, you´l need place for the character `a` itself and the number, that is 1 and the length of the written number `count` (1 for "4", 2 for "41" etc.)

Btw., your original function has a problem with empty strings (`char prev = str[0];`)